# Converting CustomAttributeTypedArguement to array

Tags: c#, attributes, type-conversion

I have a array value in a custom attribute.  The attribute looks like :

```
[ValidationTag(EntityPropertyName = "DateOfBirth" , HasBusinessLogic = true, BusinessTypes = new []{"D", "1", "P"})]
```

Using relection eventually I get the value for the BusinessTypes as follows:

```
var businessTypeArrayValue = (attr.NamedArguments[2].TypedValue);
```

Then, I cast to IEnumerable and itterate thru to add to a list.

```
var businessTypeArray = (businessTypeArrayValue.Value) as IEnumerable;

if (businessTypeArray != null)
{
   businessTypeList.AddRange(from object businessType in businessTypeArray select businessType.ToString().Trim());
}
```

This converts the data into the list - But the issue is that a value in the list looks like:

```
 "/"D/""
```

and it should be:

```
"D"
```

I have ideas on how to remove the extra characters but I would think that I should not have to do anything else on the conversion.  So the question is, how can I do the conversion and not end up with the extra characters.

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `BusinessTypes` ?

Comment: Type is String.  An array of strings